# Etymology of хорваты / Этимология слова "хорваты"

Tags: этимология, slavic

What is the possible origin of this word? Can it be related to "сарматы"?

Каково возможное происхождение этого слова? Может ли оно быть связано со словом "сарматы"?

Comment: этимология слова "хорваты" не имеет отношения к русскому языку - это всё равно что спросить об этимологии слова апачи или навахо. Это слово существует и не в русском языке и просто заимствовано. Раньше их называли кроаты. Вот например вопрос про то, как и когда кроаты стали хорватам  в русском - это да.

Comment: Этимология слова "хорваты" имеет самое прямое отношение к русскому языку, поскольку слово "хорваты" является названием славянского народа в русском языке. Утверждение о том, что "раньше их называли кроаты" - бездоказательно.

Comment: @shabunc "кроаты" - это романское искажение хорватов. Хорваты - общеславянское слово, белые хорваты сидели по Днестру, согласно "Повести временны́х лет". Вопрос об этимологии этого слова, так же как других названий славянских племён - вполне разумен.

Answer (score 5):

Origin of this word is unclear. There are many hypothesis.

- from ancient Iranian haurvata - guard of cattle (Max Fasmer. Etymological dictionary of the Russian language [Макс Фасмер. Этимологический словарь русского языка (1986)](http://etymolog.ruslang.ru/vasmer.php?id=262&vol=4%29)
- from «корванты, корвенты» - Vent, who lives on the border of the space occupied by the Veneto-Wends ([Амплеев И.А. Сербы, хорваты (2006](http://znamo-delo.narod.ru/Srbi_Hrvati.htm))
- In "etymological dictionary of Slavic Languages​​" (1981) refers to "the full etymological identity" (?!) "харваты" and "сарматы", from Iranian adjective *sarma(n)t / *harva(n)t - «female, full of women» (Амплеев И.А. Сербы, хорваты (2006). But author prejudice this hypothesis.

Comment: Я не думаю, что упомянутый Амплеев И. А. — это серьёзный автор. Стиль изложения у него любительский, выводы он делает чрезвычайно дилетантские (признаки, как Зализняк предупреждал: «любой лингвист знает» (из другой «работы») — это не аргумент), в [академии.гугля](http://scholar.google.ru) — ни единой ссылки на его работы, и вообще про него ничего не известно — кто такой, какую научную степень имеет и т. д.